# SQL select AS - prepending text

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to prepend text to an SQL select statement.  e.g.:

```
var query = "SELECT id, " +
                   "picture " 
            "FROM people";
```

to

```
var query = "SELECT id, " +
                   "picture AS './directory/' + picture "
            "FROM people";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Something like this:

```
  var query = "SELECT id, " +
              "concat('./directory/',picture) AS  picture "
              "FROM people";
```

Bit more details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Answer (score 0):

You are constructing the query as a string, so yes, you can do this.  However, you have to insert the value as a constant.  Something like:

```
var query = "SELECT id, " +
                   "picture AS " + directory " + "picture "
            "FROM people";
```

However, `directory` would need to be a value in the application and not the database (although another statement could read it).